# URL percent encoding function

Tags: strings, objective-c, ios, url

I wrote a custom URL encoding function and I'd like to run it past a few other experienced C developers. I have tested it on a few strings, and it has worked on all of them.

This is to be run on iOS devices, so memory and processor use are potentially a small concern.

Do you see any potential problems - UB, wrong return, excessive memory or processor usage, difficulty reading?

Any suggestions for improvement?

```
NSString *urlEncode(NSString *orig)
{
    static const BOOL safe[0x100] = {
        ['a'...'z'] = YES,
        ['A'...'Z'] = YES,
        ['0'...'9'] = YES,
        ['-'] = YES,
        ['_'] = YES,
        ['.'] = YES,
        ['~'] = YES
    };
    const char *digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    const char *cstr = orig.UTF8String;
    int clen = orig.length;
    int nlen = 3*clen;
    char newstr[nlen + 1];

    const char *o = cstr   + clen;
    char *p = newstr + nlen;
    *p = 0;
    while(o > cstr) {
        unsigned char c = *--o;
        if(safe[c]) {
            *--p = c;
        } else {
            *--p = digits[c&0xf];
            *--p = digits[c>>4];
            *--p = '%';
        }
    }
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:p];
    return str;
}
```

Yes, `newStr` could get long, but given that a URL > 2kB is unreliable, I think it's unlikely to be a problem in reality.

Comment: Seems like you should be able to just use `NSString`'s `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`? Or, if you need to expand on what is escaped (as you likely would to implement a true URL encoding), you should be able to use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` (example of custom escaping: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8086845/567864)

Comment: `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` doesn't convert everything it should. Sure, I could use `CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes` (and have for other projects), but I thought I'd roll my own this time.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, URL encoding is more [nuanced](http://www.skorks.com/2010/05/what-every-developer-should-know-about-urls/) than you might think.  Be cautious when applying encoding.

As for your code, the only blatant bug I see is that it can segfault when encoding a non-ASCII string.  The [`-length`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/length) method returns the number of Unicode characters in the string.  Since you are working one `char` at a time, you need the number of bytes instead.

```
NSUInteger clen = [orig lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSUInteger nlen = 3 * clen;
```

It would be better to change the method signature to:

```
NSString *urlEncode(const NSString *orig)
```

I think that using a `for` loop would improve readability.  Currently, you declare/initialize `*o`, test it, and decrement it on three separate lines.  A `for` loop would provide an instantly recognizable structure to make it obvious how those three lines of code are related:

```
for (const char *o = cstr + clen - 1; o >= cstr; o--) {
    unsigned char c = *o;
    if (safe[c]) {
        *--p = c;
    } else {
        *--p = digits[c & 0x0f];
        *--p = digits[c >> 4];
        *--p = '%';
    }
}
```

The null `char` would be better written as `'\0'`.

Personally, I would choose to iterate forward rather than backward through the string, as it simplifies the loop by a few instructions, and is easier to understand.  It also gives you the option of calling `-maximumLengthOfBytesUsingEncoding` (which runs in O(1) time) instead of `-lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding`.

```
unsigned char c;
char *p = newstr;
for (const char *o = cstr; (c = *o); o++) {
    ...
}
```